# How to fetch String value in angularjs from model.addAttribute(Spring controller)?

Tags: angularjs

How to fetch the string value in angularjs from `model.addAttribute(Spring controller)`?

```
<div ng-if="error">
    <div class="error">{{error}}</div>
</div>
```

So, I want to check the value of that model attribute.

Comment: Not clearly. Could you please post more codes or a plunker?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, Model model) {
  if (error != null) {
   model.addAttribute("error", "Unable to authenticate your user name and password.");
  }
  return "login1";
 }
In the above code I want to fetch that error variable value in jsp using angularjs ?